# Filling DataFrame with unique positive integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this

```
   col1 col2 col3  col4 col5  
 0   0   1    0     1     1
 1   0   1    0     0     1
```

I want to assign a unique positive integer greater than 1 to each 0 entry.

so I want a DataFrame that looks like this

```
      col1 col2  col3  col4 col5    
    0  2    1     3     1    1
    1  4    1     5     6    1
```

The integers don't have to be from an ordered sequence, just positive and unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.arange(...).reshape(df.shape)` generates a dataframe the sive of `df` consisting of continuous integers starting at 2.

`df.where(df, ...)` works because your dataframe consists of binary indicators (zeros and ones).  It keeps all true values (i.e. the ones) and then uses the continuous numpy array to fill in the zeros.

```
# optional: inplace=True
>>> df.where(df, np.arange(start=2, stop=df.shape[0] * df.shape[1] + 2).reshape(df.shape))  
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     2     1     4     1     1
1     7     1     9    10     1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [numpy.arange](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) for generating unique random numbers with [`shape`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html) and replace all `0` by boolean mask generating by `df == 0`:

```
print df
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     0     1     0     1     1
1     0     1     0     0     1

print df == 0
   col1   col2  col3   col4   col5
0  True  False  True  False  False
1  True  False  True   True  False

print df.shape
(2, 5)

#count of integers
min_count = df.shape[0] * df.shape[1]
print min_count
10

#you need add 2, because omit 0 and 1
print np.arange(start=2, stop=min_count + 2).reshape(df.shape)
[[ 2  3  4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11]]

#use integers from 2 to max count of values of df
df[ df == 0 ] = np.arange(start=2, stop=min_count + 2).reshape(df.shape)
print df
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     2     1     4     1     1
1     7     1     9    10     1
```

Or use [numpy.random.choice](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) for bigger unique random integers:

```
#count of integers
min_count = df.shape[0] * df.shape[1]
print min_count
10
#you can use bigger number in np.arange, e.g. 100, but minimal is min_count + 2
df[ df == 0 ] = np.random.choice(np.arange(2, 100), replace=False, size=df.shape)
print df
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0    17     1    53     1     1
1    39     1    15    76     1
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee uniqueness.  You can pick the same random number.

Comment: @Alexander - you are right. I edit answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, although it isn't the greatest performance in pandas:

```
import random

MAX_INT = 100

for row in df:
    for col in row:
        if col == 0:
            col == random.randrange(1, MAX_INT)
```

Something like `itertuples()` will be faster, but if it's not a lot of data this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df == 0] = np.random.choice(np.arange(2, df.size + 2), replace=False, size=df.shape)
```

Lot of already good answers here but throwing this out there.

1. `replace` indicates whether the sample is with or without replacement.
2. `np.arange` is from (`2`, `size of the df + 2`). It's `2` because you want it greater than 1.
3. `size` has to be the same shape as `df` so I just used `df.shape`

To illustrate what array values `np.random.choice` generates:

```
>>> np.random.choice(np.arange(2, df.size + 2), replace=False, size=df.shape)
array([[11,  4,  6,  5,  9],
       [ 7,  8, 10,  3,  2]])
```

Note that they are all greater than 1 and are all unique.

Before:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     0     1     0     1     1
1     0     1     0     0     1
```

After:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     9     1     7     1     1
1     6     1     3    11     1
```